# C: Hofstadter Q sequence with recursion

Tags: c, recursion

I've to write a C function that print on screen the first N elements of Hofstadter Q sequence by using recursion.

Hofstadter Q sequence definition is:

> Q(1)=Q(2)=2
>
> Q(n)= Q(n-Q(n-1)) + Q(n-Q(n-2))

My code should be ok, but I don't know where to put the printf to print the results.

First numbers are: 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 9, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 16, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 16, 20, 17, 17, 20, 21, 19, 20, 22, 21, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 32, 24, 25, 30, 28, 26, 30, 30 etc.

My code is actually:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int hof(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    int flag;

    printf("How many elements to print: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    flag=hof(n);

    return 0;
}

int hof(int n) {
    int res;

    if (n < 3) res = 1;
    else res=hof(n-(hof(n-1)))+hof(n-(hof(n-2)));

    return res;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code and the initial part of the sequence suggests that Q(1)=Q(2)=1, not 2.

Comment: [Wikipedia thinks so too...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter_sequence#Hofstadter_Q_sequence)

Comment: Taking this approach will quickly bring you to stack overflow (besides other problems mentioned in the answers)

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I don't think that stack overflow would come quickly enough, considering how slow this implementation is. Running this for `n` of 500 would take ages, without overflowing the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code repeatedly calculates same set of sub-sequences. That means it's both inefficient and there's no single place in your code where you can "insert" the printf.

Using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), it can be done as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arr[512];

int hof(int n);
int main(void) {

    int n;
    int flag;

    printf("How many elements to print: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    flag=hof(n);

    for(size_t i = 1; arr[i]; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    return 0;
}

int hof(int n){
    int res;

    if (arr[n]) return arr[n];

    if (n < 3) res = 1;
    else res=hof(n-(hof(n-1)))+hof(n-(hof(n-2)));

    arr[n] = res;
    return res;
}
```

You can change the array size as per your needs or use `malloc()` to dynamically allocate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I edited the code as you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `printf` goes in the loop:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++) {
    printf("%d ", hof(i));
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/rmVfHk)

However, you will quickly learn that your implementation is very slow for even a modest value of `n`: printing 42 elements takes more than five seconds on very fast hardware, while printing 100 elements will keep you waiting for a very long time.

This is because you keep re-computing the same values in the recursive call over and over. Instead, you should compute each value once, and use its value in all subsequent computations.

If you would like to keep things recursive, use [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Othrewise, restructure your algorithm to use a [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach.

Coding up either of these two approaches has very high instructive value, so I wouldn't spoil it for you by suggesting an implementation.

Comment: I'm guessing that the original question (hw?) requested to print using recursion as well.. I.e., as part of the computation process

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I don't think the printing as part of recursion has been part of the assignment. I think their instructor wants the students to discover a specific problem and discover a solution for it.